# Edit an .exe file from a C++ program

Tags: c++, c, file-handling

I am editing a FileA.exe in my main program of C++ , I want to add a new function(
**void NewFunction(...){...}**
) inside FileA.exe(that must be exported). How can I do this in C++.

Comment: You can't do that just like that. I think you need to read up on how an executable file is created (compiling, linking, ...).

Comment: I know that how compiling and linking works but the problem is that I only have the .exe file, which I want to edit and add a new function inside it. is there any other work around? for edit the file and also make a .lib file correspond to that?

Comment: The only chance to edit an `.exe` file is to use a hex editor (with intimate knowledge what all the bytes in the binary mean) or a disassembler or decompiler (e.g. [IDA Pro](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/)). Are you really sure you want to go that way?

Comment: @abdullahtoqeer You would need knowledge of how the [PE format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable) works and how to properly modify it without making it invalid.

Comment: What do you expect the effect of adding a function to an existing exe would be? You do not expect the new function to be called and executed during execution of the edited exe, are you? It would not be, because the rest of the program does not know about the new function and no part of it will call it. Please take one logical step back and explain about what you want to achieve by doing what you describe. I.e. consider whether we might be looking at a https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: What are you _actually_ trying to achive. This question sounds very much like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) to me

Comment: I am hooking some functions inside an .exe file. but the problem is when I hook them and call should be redirect to my hooked function, which is outside the address space of the .exe file but it is not coming there. So I only want to add a dummy function inside the .exe file and want to redirect call there.

Comment: @Scheff I tried IDA also, but it does not change the orignal file. and make a new one, which is of very big size. I only want a few bytes to be add inside it.

Comment: So your *real* question is: "How can I hook some function in an EXE file so that my code is called instead of the original?" If that's right, please [edit] your question showing what you have tried, what you got, and what you expect. A [example] would help to get some attention, too. ;-)

Comment: Yes, Some function which is not in an .exe but i want to add it and it should be exported function, so we may call it from another .exe. I also want a .lib file for that .exe

Comment: To use with hooking, you can add the function not into the EXE file but into the running process instead, using VirtualAllocEx and WriteProcessMemory (IIRC). Your original function should be position-independent though, or you will have to relocate it.

Comment: Also it is possible to use a dirty trick: call `CreateRemoteThread` using `LoadLibraryA` as the thread function. You still need to place the path into target’s memory, though, but that’s way easier than injecting a whole function manually.